# Why oxygen bubbles are larger than hydrogen bubbles during water electrolysis?

Tags: surface-tension, buoyancy, electrochemistry

During water electrolysis, I found the oxygen bubbles are usually larger than the hydrogen bubbles.

I think the reason is because different gases have different contact angles. The contact angle of the oxygen is larger than the hydrogen that cause the size of oxygen bubbles are lager than the hydrogen bubbles.If my assumption is right, could you please explain why the contact angle is different for different gases?

I have captured some videos that can prove the oxygen bubbles are larger than hydrogen when they are going to detach from the surface.
The link: https://vimeo.com/283578077
The top is hydrogen and bottom is oxygen.

Comment: Please post links to the videos. This would be useful.

Comment: The link has been attached.

Comment: Sorry, we couldn’t find that page

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for posting the videos. It is not obvious what we are seeing here. Can you point out what to look? I see things whizzing past at the top, and nothing happening at the bottom. I don't think I am seeing any lift-off events.

Comment: This is because the video is just a short part of the bubble growth. I think you noticed the  bubbles (oxygen) on the bottom edge are very large compared with the bubbles(hydrogen) on the top edge. I observed this phenomena many times in different conditions and think the oxygen bubbles during the water electrolysis should be larger than hydrogen bubbles, I'm not sure if this is reasonable or not.

Comment: There are some bubbles on top edge detach from the surface at small size.